# What does the @Id annotation?

Tags: java, mongodb, annotations, jongo

I have a class that has this note, `@Id`, what is the use of it?

```
package oknok.validacao.resources;

import org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.Id;

public class Validacao {

    @Id
    String id;
    String email;
    String instancia;
    String dataCriacao;
    String dataAtualizacao;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This annotation marks a field as a Mongo document identifier.

> unique identifier available on every Mongo document. If it isn't
>   setted, it is generated. To handle it with Jongo, one attribute has to
>   be named _id or annotated with @Id (alias for @JsonProperty("_id"))

quoted from [jongo spec](http://jongo.org/)

You can read more about Mongo document ID [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).

Comment: Exact, note that this annotation will be replaced by @MongoId in version 1.2

Answer (score -1):

Check this link :
"Specifies the primary key of an entity. The field or property to which the Id annotation is applied should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date; java.math.BigDecimal; java.math.BigInteger."

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html

Comment: the question is not related to JPA